# copying not a scpecific number of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

first I'm not good in coding just trying figure my way and make what i need.
so my function is  to copy data from sheet to sheet and delete the data after finishing.
my issue is small but can't find a solution for it, it's when I'm copying it copy just 12 rows, but for me i want it to copy as much rows will be.
my final code i want it to copy the rows that have a specific word, but for now I'm searching for a solution for this issue.

````
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

 // get source range
var range = copySheet.getRange(2,1,12,4);
var source = range.getValues();
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,12,4).setValues(source);
range.clearContent();

// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,12,1);


// clear source values 
Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
}```

this is my code
thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

In this example, the script gets all values from Sheet1, not just 12 rows.  It then uses the Array.filter() to get all rows that have the word "Hello" in Column A.  Not knowing how many rows match the filter I use source.length to tell getRange() how many rows to output.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

    // get source range
    var range = copySheet.getDataRange();  // Get all values
    var source = range.getValues();
    source = source.filter( row => row[0] === "Hello" ); 
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,source.length,source[0].length).setValues(source);
    // clear source values 
    range.clearContent();

    Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: the problem for this code it's deleting all the data even the ones who doesn't have the hello word

Comment: Is I noted this script "gets all values from Sheet1, not just 12 rows".  If you want only 12 rows adjust the range

Comment: yes i got u but it takes all the data , i want to take specific cells but the maximum of rows